# Why the app crashes, when I trying to set a text size attribute via custom style

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-styles

When I trying to apply a custom style to my `TextView`, and trying to specify the textSize attribute not via value in sp I got an app crash. The code is listed below.

```
<style name="TextViewRegistrationStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
```

When I specify the value in such way:

```
<style name="TextViewRegistrationStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

Everything works fine. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textSize` is simple dimension attribute and `textAppearance` is complex attribute consisting of several values. You receive error because those two are not compatible.

`textSize` declaration: `<attr name="textSize" format="dimension" />`

`textAppearance` declaration:

```
<declare-styleable name="TextAppearance">
    <!-- Text color. -->
    <attr name="textColor" />
    <!-- Size of the text. Recommended dimension type for text is "sp" for scaled-pixels (example: 15sp). -->
    <attr name="textSize" />
    <!-- Style (bold, italic, bolditalic) for the text. -->
    <attr name="textStyle" />
    <!-- Typeface (normal, sans, serif, monospace) for the text. -->
    <attr name="typeface" />
    <!-- Font family (named by string) for the text. -->
    <attr name="fontFamily" />
    <!-- Color of the text selection highlight. -->
    <attr name="textColorHighlight" />
    <!-- Color of the hint text. -->
    <attr name="textColorHint" />
    <!-- Color of the links. -->
    <attr name="textColorLink" />
    <!-- Present the text in ALL CAPS. This may use a small-caps form when available. -->
    <attr name="textAllCaps" format="boolean" />
    <!-- Place a blurred shadow of text underneath the text, drawn with the
         specified color. The text shadow produced does not interact with
         properties on View that are responsible for real time shadows,
         {@link android.R.styleable#View_elevation elevation} and
         {@link android.R.styleable#View_translationZ translationZ}. -->
    <attr name="shadowColor" format="color" />
    <!-- Horizontal offset of the text shadow. -->
    <attr name="shadowDx" format="float" />
    <!-- Vertical offset of the text shadow. -->
    <attr name="shadowDy" format="float" />
    <!-- Blur radius of the text shadow. -->
    <attr name="shadowRadius" format="float" />
    <!-- Elegant text height, especially for less compacted complex script text. -->
    <attr name="elegantTextHeight" format="boolean" />
    <!-- Text letter-spacing. -->
    <attr name="letterSpacing" format="float" />
    <!-- Font feature settings. -->
    <attr name="fontFeatureSettings" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

---

What you can do is to create your own modified text appearance style and assign that to `textAppearance` instead of `textSize`.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Registration" parent="android:TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewRegistrationStyle">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Registration</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```